# validate input element nested in ng-repeat also on page load, not only on change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I have an angularjs page.  I made a custom directive in order to validate an input element that is nested in an ng-repeat.  Now, the validation works, but I also need it to work on page load and on changes that happen on the page (like drop down selected and button clicked), not only when the user changes the value.  I also need to add the the directive (or to the validation) to see if there is a value for a filter from a controller on this module.

Any suggestions?  Here is my current code:

```
.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attr, mCtrl) {
            function myValidation(value) {
                mCtrl.$setValidity('charE', false);
                if (value>1){                    
                    mCtrl.$setValidity('charE', true);
                } else {
                    mCtrl.$setValidity('charE', false);
                }
                return value;
            }
            mCtrl.$parsers.push(myValidation);
        }
    };
})
```

here is my call to it:

```
<td align="center">
    <form name="myForm">
        <!--<input name="myInput" ng-model="myInput" required my-directive>-->
        <input type="number" name="myInput" ng-model="item.qtyToOrder" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" ng-change="SavePO(item.qtyToReOrder, item.qtyToOrder,  {{$index}})" required my-directive/>
        <!--<span>test  - {{myForm.myInput.$valid}}</span>-->
    </form>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

was able to do it straight on the DOM.

```
 <input  ng-class="{ 'has-error': item.qtyToOrder<=0 && filter.vendor !='' }" type="number" name="myInput" ng-model="item.qtyToOrder" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" ng-change="SavePO(item.qtyToReOrder, item.qtyToOrder,  {{$index}})" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `ngOnInit() {}` helps with your problem!

see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/OnInit-interface.html

Comment: that looks very complicated to follow.  it also doesn't handle the other situations like button click and drop down change.